# Search table based on infromation from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a temporary that has been populated correctly but now I want to search another table based on two fields that are contained within my temporary table. These fields are `Forename` and `Surname`. But I want to search for multiple student names and quantities and return specified data! I think the problem will be better explained in the images below:

**My Temporary Table**

[image]

**The Table I would like to search (Table2)**

[image]

Once I have searched each student name I want to be returned with the students `Forename, Surname Address, Pin and Score`!

Below shows how I have been trying to achieve this without any luck!

```
Select TempTable.Forname, TempTable.Surmname, Table2.Address, Table2.Pin 
from TempTable
Where Exists ( Select * from Table2
               where Table2.Forname=TempTable.Forname and
               Table2.Surname=TempTable.Surname
              )
```

But it is returning me no results and I don't know why!

Comment: To achieve your goal you need to research how to perform JOINS between two tables.  Have a play and if you get stuck come back and show us what you have tried.

Comment: I know how to do joins! I just made it very complicated in my own head when the solution was very simple!

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly your question, the way to do it is just a simple join:

```
select TempTable.Forename, TempTable.Surname, Table2.Address, Table2.Pin 
from TempTable
inner join Table2 on Table2.Forename = TempTable.Forename and Table2.Surname = TempTable.Surname
```

Though i recommend you to have a primary key on the "Persons" table (Table2) and use this primary key to reference the records on TepTable

Answer (score 2):

The EXISTS is only used to "filter" result, it's columns aren't available outside the EXISTS.

You need a JOIN!

```
Select TempTable.Forname, TempTable.Surmname, Table2.Address, Table2.Pin 
from TempTable JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Forname=TempTable.Forname and Table2.Surname=TempTable.Surname;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really have called the columns "Forname" you just need a simple join. This does it explicitly to keep close to your original:

```
SELECT TempTable.Forname, TempTable.Surmname, Table2.Address, Table2.Pin 
FROM TempTable tt, Table2 t2
WHERE tt.Forename = t2.Forename
AND tt.Surname = t2.Surname;
```

You could do the same with `INNER JOIN`.

This is all assuming that student names are unique.